# How to use GPT-4 vision?

Tags: front-end, chatai, llm, openai, gpt

How exactly do you call GPT vision, both programmatically and in chat-enabled notebooks?

It seems like the image is being downsized when pasted inline, and it is unclear how many prior cells are in the history window that the current chat cell can reference.

Does anyone know how best to use it?

Comment: This may not be an answer, but may help. Once you have connected to the OpenAI service (requires an account with OpenAI) you can choose the model you use in the AI settings (in the Mathematica Preferences menu). I get the preview version of GPT-4 1106 Vision and GPT-4 Vision as options. The differences in the models I am not too sure of. It seems also that GPT-4 Turbo also has similar capabilities. There are image size restrictions (low-res is 1024 x 1024 and high res 2048 x 4096 (high detail) or 4096 x 8192 (low detail). They all have different costs in terms of tokens....

Comment: It seems to me that dealing with the number of tokens (linked of course to cost) is tricky to estimate. To be really efficient in combining images with a chat block, one should have a bit of an idea of how to estimate the number of tokens that one is sending and how close this is to the limit that you have. I have only played around a bit until now, but often reach the token limit for my OpenAI account meaning I have to start a new chat block. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have written several examples of programmatically GPT-4-vision-preview in Mathematica on my blog, using Anton Antonov's code. https://jschrier.github.io/blog/tag/gpt4v (too busy to write this up now)

Comment: This is a built in feature, and I believe it was even called out specifically in the version 14 release blogpost, shouldn't it have documentation?